# If statements in javascript, which is better?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When writing javascript or PHP for that matter I use two ways to write if statements.

#### Return as soon as possible

Below I try to end the function as soon as possible. If the value is not what I expect, return it. The benefit I see here is that I don't need `{}` and I don't need to nest anything.

```js
function hello(value = null) {
  if(!value) return;

  console.log("I'm still here!");
  console.log("End of function");
}
```

#### Do something on match

In this case I don't return at all. Instead I do something if I get a "match". The upside here is that I don't need to return anything.

```js
function hello(value = null) {
  if(value) {
    console.log("I'm still here!");
    console.log("End of function");
  }
}
```

So which is better? One of them or equally good?

Comment: I like the first because it keeps the indentation to a minimum, but this question is really going to collect opinions, which is not what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Note that a value can be "false" even if it's not `null`.

Comment: I'm also a fan of the first one. Otherwise you get into a stacked indentation sideways pyramid when you have more than one condition and some loops. But, again, opinion based - some dislike multiple exits of a function.

Comment: I don't believe there's a performatic difference, so what's more easy to understand would be my call

Comment: Even though it does not cost a lot, in terms of performance we should consider `branch prediction`. So, I would suggest to think about `misprediction cost`. Since it depends on your code, the answer may vary.